# Using SSL for connection between GeoNetwork and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, tomcat, geonetwork

I use GeoNetwork 3.10.6 in Tomcat as a service and want to connect to a Postgres 12.8 db on another server via ssl. I think, I have to change something in the jdbc.properties file.

I tried something like: `jdbc.connectionProperties=ssl=true` but no success.

Does anyone have experience with it?

Comment: Did you change the configuration in your postgresql.conf to use ssl? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ssl-tcp.html

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is in some GeoNetwork configuration. I can reconstruct the problem when I turn ssl off in pgadmin and then try to connect. The same error appears in geonetwork-log and pgadmin: "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "someIP", user "user", database "db", SSL off"